# How to subscribe to events fired from any collection element in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, events

I have made the following Dictionary, and I would like to be able to subscribe to the event fired from any of its' elements, in order to know which dictionary elements' properties were changed.

Here is my class:

```
public class BlockInput : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = Value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}
```

I create a concurrent dictionary like the following:

```
  public ConcurrentDictionary<string, BlockInput> Inputs;
```

How would this be achieved, in order for me to find every time that one of the BlockInput values were changed/event for each element fired?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you have another way than manually subscribing to all events yourself:

```cs
foreach (BlockInput item in Inputs.Values) {
    item.PropertyChanged += BlockInput_PropertyChanged;
}
```

```cs
private void BlockInput_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var blockInput = sender as BlockInput; // Get the item that was changed
    // Do stuff
}
```

You would have to subscribe to all added items and unsubscribe from removed ones as well if you plan to add or remove items from the `Dictionary`.

Answer (score -1):

In practical use of this Interface (wich is primarily MVVM) usually this is enough. You have the GUI classes do all the plumbing work of subscribing to events. You only need to provide 3 Change Notifications:

1. The one of each property of `BlockInput`. You did that in your example code.
2. The one if something is added or removed from the Collection. That is what `ObservableCollection<BlockInput>` will take care off. It is also the only thing the OC will take care off.
3. The one on the property exposing the `ObservableCollection<BlockInput>`. The OC is notoriously bad at bulk modifications, so often you need to prepare a new instance in code, with Exposing being the last step.

If you do not have a MVVM use case, please leave a comment. I can think of 2 ways on top of manually subscribing to each Event.